# How to convert this PHP salt creation code to modern Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, typescript, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to convert this combination of PHP functions to an equivalent in JavaScript:

**PHP**

```php
public function generate_api_key() 
{
  $salt = base_convert(bin2hex(random_bytes(64)), 16, 36);

  $new_key = substr($salt, 0, 40);

  return $new_key;
}
```

What I currently have, is the following:

**JavaScript**

```js
export function generateKey() {
  const salt = crypto.randomBytes(SALT_BYTES_API_KEY).toString('hex');

  const saltAsNumber = BigInt(parseInt(salt, 16));

  const base36Representation = saltAsNumber.toString(36);

  return base36Representation.substring(0, 39);
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the result of the php function results in the following examples:

```
40ssww8kksocgk8wk8kw0o0k0gccks4ogssoooos
8ogckg08kg00cg8ccwo8wogogw88ogwsocss4sgg
4sgcks88gc8s84w8so4gskk4w8o0488kc0cs4k0k
8k4csgwogwskcc0c8skcw4g4cggk0wwsksgksgk0
```

So it's always compromised of a specific subset of numbers and letters.

While my JavaScript implementation returns the following:

```
b1xvdp7rrvv5qu0irtbel5mnukq2rrlr18nyn9e
czi946fhght4wk5wrowagqq79eo53i8k3ikawd5
9z5loch3dacs4oe30ncmxh3qb3htbhkwp9dajlf
i1yryhixebxfy2tr93ppegc0mmzhnc5cdwb2ogb
```

Which seems like a different subset of numbers/letters and more varied.

I do not know enough of encryption and conversion to really know what I am doing wrong or how far I am from the correct approach to this.

Comment: Seems like you just need a string of random characters... so does it matter?

Comment: “Base 36” means 0-9 and a-z are your possible characters. Therefor I rather doubt if your observed “subsets” are actually such, guess it would be more likely that you drew the wrong conclusion from too small a set of test data.

Comment: _"I do not know enough of encryption and conversion to really know what I am doing wrong"_ - That's when you use a tried and tested library to do it for you. Creating a secure salt isn't trivial. Also, it doesn't matter if the salt "looks the same as others" or not.

Comment: @misorude I was thinking that as well for a while but I've been rows and rows of these keys and it is always the same subset. I even tried it out in PHP playground and I got the same result. It is very strange.

Comment: We cannot run your code, so we can't verify anything. From PHP `$this->security->get_random_bytes()` is missing, and from the Javascript `crypto.randomBytes()` is missing. Essential stuff. How do you expect us to answer your question?

Comment: Could also be that `$this->security->get_random_bytes` and `crypto.randomBytes` have different opinions on what “random” means. If your input data isn’t _actually_ random, but has certain “quirks” in that regard maybe, it could explain noticeable “patterns” in the two different outputs as well.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'm sorry the PHP function is just `random_bytes`, which is built in and can be used in a PHP playground. `crypto` is part of node JS if that helps.

Comment: @misorude maybe you're right. It was just a bit confusing but I guess I'll stick with this solution then.

Comment: In PHP, you're currently creating a large random string but are only using a part of it. Just create it as large as you need it to begin with.

Comment: From some testing I did it is clear that the `base_convert()` function causes the limited set of characters used in the PHP version: `0,4,8,c,g,k,o,s,w`. Even I can see the pattern there. There must be an interference between the hex number and the base 36 numbering system. Is there a mathematician in the house?

Comment: I think the OP needs to do some debugging on the PHP, e.g. log the values of the intermediate results in the function.